# Error Syncing File

Tags: files

Client is running 3.5.14.  They have a Team channel, with one of the fields to allow them to upload a vCard for the team member.  Everthing is working fine.  However, the client asked me today if there was a way to clean up the old files.  I went into the Files area and they are not showing up.  If I try to sync, I get the error message that "vcf: The file type you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Even though the files were uploading ok, I needed to reference it in system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Config/mimes.php file.

```
'text/x-vcard', // .vcf - vCard
```